# R won't interpret table column as numerical values

Tags: r

I am just trying to convert a column of numbers, which R thinks are characters, to numerical values.

I have the following table:

```
> longtab=as.data.frame(table(long));head(longtab)
    long Freq
1 189485    1
2 189486    1
3 189487    1
4 189488    1
5 189489    1
6 189490    1
```

I've created a new table from those data as follows:

```
> q=head(longtab);q
    long Freq
1 189485    1
2 189486    1
3 189487    1
4 189488    1
5 189489    1
6 189490    1
```

When I test whether the "long" column is numeric, R tells me that it is not.

```
> is.numeric(q$long)
[1] FALSE
```

When I try to coerce "long" values to be numeric using as.numeric(), I get the following:

```
> as.numeric(q$long)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

But these are the row numbers not the values in the "long" column. This seems like it should be a simple problem to fix but I am struggling and have been at this a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will give what you want `as.numeric(as.character(q$long))`.

Comment: @Digsby: I believe that OceanSky_U is probably correct. Your "long" column was a factor (as evidenced by the result of coercing to to numeric class.) Factors often print in a a manner that makes then appear to be numbers. Commonly this occurred when Excel spreadsheets were imported with read.* functions, because any notes end up coercing the result to factor. It's probably a bit less common in the most recent version of R. You might only need `as.numeric` now that the default for the read.table parameter, stringsAsFactors, has been changed to FALSE.

Comment: `table()` will always turn the values you are counting into factors. It doesn't expect to work with numeric values. A base R solution that would work is: `y<-aggregate(long, list(value = long), length)` which skips the `table()` step altogether.